How to fix APFS errors that Disk First Aid isn't fixing? ("descendants of dir-stats object is greater than expected")
This is occurring on an M1 MacBook Pro 2021, macOS Sequoia 15.1.1.
I've seen some warnings/errors running disk first aid through Disk Utility. I see the same errors running it from the command line. I run this on the data partition:
fsck_apfs -n -l -S /dev/disk3s5

I get the following output:
** Checking the container superblock.
   Checking the checkpoint with transaction ID 16750499.
** Checking the space manager.
** Checking the space manager free queue trees.
** Checking the object map.
** Checking the encryption key structures.
** Checking volume /dev/rdisk3s5.
** Checking the APFS volume superblock.
   The volume Data was formatted by newfs_apfs (1933.41.2) and last modified by apfs_kext (2313.41.1).
** Checking the object map.
** Checking the snapshot metadata tree.
** Checking the snapshot metadata.
** Checking the document ID tree.
** Checking the fsroot tree.
warning: physical_size (1728512) of dir-stats object (id 257496) is greater than expected (892928)
warning: descendants (7164) of dir-stats object (id 257569) is greater than expected (4595)
warning: descendants (8586) of dir-stats object (id 294597) is greater than expected (6774)
warning: physical_size (18556170240) of dir-stats object (id 6004524) is greater than expected (8192)
warning: descendants (597) of dir-stats object (id 36688329) is greater than expected (591)
error: doc-id tree: record exists for doc-id 212, file-id 6082371 but no inode references this doc-id
error: doc-id tree: record exists for doc-id 267, file-id 7047399 but no inode references this doc-id
error: doc-id tree: record exists for doc-id 269, file-id 7482063 but no inode references this doc-id
error: doc-id tree: record exists for doc-id 317, file-id 8785645 but no inode references this doc-id
error: doc-id tree: record exists for doc-id 326, file-id 9042796 but no inode references this doc-id
error: doc-id tree: record exists for doc-id 327, file-id 9043038 but no inode references this doc-id
error: doc-id tree: record exists for doc-id 337, file-id 9124874 but no inode references this doc-id
error: doc-id tree: record exists for doc-id 341, file-id 9134975 but no inode references this doc-id
error: doc-id tree: record exists for doc-id 345, file-id 9174308 but no inode references this doc-id
error: doc-id tree: record exists for doc-id 347, file-id 9592542 but no inode references this doc-id
error: doc-id tree: record exists for doc-id 350, file-id 9844081 but no inode references this doc-id
error: doc-id tree: record exists for doc-id 357, file-id 10537522 but no inode references this doc-id
error: doc-id tree: record exists for doc-id 388, file-id 11569171 but no inode references this doc-id
** Checking the extent ref tree.
** Checking the file key rolling tree.
** Verifying volume object map space.
** The volume /dev/rdisk3s5 with UUID EF29AB14-3040-4F56-A943-557A025875B6 was found to be corrupt and needs to be repaired.
** Verifying allocated space.
** Performing deferred repairs.
** The volume /dev/rdisk3s5 with UUID EF29AB14-3040-4F56-A943-557A025875B6 appears to be OK.

I've run this, (without '-n -l -S'), several times in repair mode (as suggested in various places), both in normal user mode and in recovery mode. It never seems to change.  I've deleted the partition snapshots too, without any change to these messages.
So, first question, is… what's wrong? And is it actually 'repaired' as it suggests? Yet probably not, because I get the same every time I run the disk check?
And next question is, how do I know what doc-id 337, file-id 9124874 refers to? Apple documentation is particularly useless here. (What's the point of an error message if there's nowhere to find out what it means!?).
Then there's the descendants (8586) of dir-stats object (id 294597) is greater than expected (6774) message. Where do I find object 'id 294597' so I can try and check its size?

@Giacomo,  I ran Disk first aid to try and fix what seems to be a recurring failure with macOS.  Namely,  when I move files off the MacBook (apfs) drive to and external drive via cli,  it does not release any file space.  Ie,  there is 'purgeable' space that is not free. One suggestion, (since Apple do not give any), was to repair the disk to recover the space. Of course, that didn't work.

@Giacomo,  The actual 'what is wrong' is that the error messages don't mean anything to the average user, so are effectively useless.  They don't help address the issue that is supposedly creating an error. So I can't tell if it's a problem about to happen, or if I have corrupted files somewhere on my system.

@Giacomo, thanks, I'll look at Onxy.  Not sure why the cache would cause such issues, but it may clean more space.

John: The -n option means "Never attempt to repair any damage that is found". I thought you were trying to make repairs. Similarly, the -l option means " Enable live verification mode. This makes it possible to check an APFS container which is currently mounted read-write, although no repairs can be made." and the -S option means "Skip iteration of snapshots (top-level snapshot structures will still be checked), although no repairs can be made.".

Yes,  I'm aware of that.   This was the fsck_apfs run after trying the actual repair in recovery mode so that I could copy paste the output into this post.
I admit that I did not make that clear in the text, that a 'real' run was made earlier.  I've corrected that now,
